# How to find duplicate values based on column in two spreadsheets and check if the row is an exact match

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two excel spreadsheets: Header2018 and Header2019

they both contain the same column headers, but with different record entries. Some of these entries are the same, and I want to find which ones.

I want to merge all the duplicate records (based on the column: asset_id) into a new spreadsheet, and then check if there is any difference between the rest of the columns.

Example
Header 2018:

```
asset_id    Name    Country

2          Trent      CAN
3          Alex       CAN
4          Derek      CAN
5          Louis      CAN
6          Teresa     CAN
```

Header 2019:

```
asset_id    Name    Country
4          Derek      CAN
5          Louis      USA
1          Kate       CAN
7          Pat        CAN
8          Steven     CAN
9          Tom        CAN
```

Resulting Table:

```
asset_id    Name    Country
4          Derek      CAN
5          Louis      CAN
4          Derek      CAN
5          Louis      USA
```

Based on the resulting table I want to be able to find records where the asset_id is the same, but another column is different.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Power Query to get the result.

1. add 2 Tables to Power Query-under Power Query editor- go to Home- Append 2 Queries:
   [image]
2. Select asset_id column- go to Transform- Select Group By- select Advanced- Add aggregation- Type a name for New Column and select All Rows:
   [image]
3. Expand Table for and select Name and Country- Filter Count column >2, remove Count column- Close and load:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

*I would like suggest method, needs Helper Columns & an Array Formula to extract common Rows from both Sheets:*

**Sheet 1:**

[image]

- Formula in Cell `A2` for *Helper Value*:

`=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$7, B2)`

---

**Sheet 2:**

[image]

- Formula in Cell `A2`:

`=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6, B2)`

**N.B.**

- If both Sheet has number of Duplicate Ids (*are more than 2*) then, instead of **COUNTIF**, better use this Formula to find *Duplicates*.

  `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,Sheet2!B$2:B$7,0)),"","Duplicate")`
- *And in **Master Sheet** criteria in Cell `E59` would be **Duplicate** instead of **1**.*

---

**Master Sheet:**

[image]

- An Array Formula in Cell `G60`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$6, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($E$59, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6), ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$6)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$6))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$D$7, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($E$59, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7), ROW(Sheet2!$B$2:$D$7)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$B$2:$D$7))+1), ABS(ROW(A1)-2)), COLUMN(A1)),""))}
  ```
- Finish Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, fill right then down.
- In Array formula `ABS(ROW(A1)-2))` is been used to adjust *Row number* for `Sheet 2` to `1`.

*You may adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*